# How to use spring boot remote commands from putty when application is running on remote server

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am using spring boot remote commands using groovy scripts and I am also able to test them from local machine using putty. But I am not sure how to make it work when the application is running on remote server. There is no such help available on spring boot documentation.
Do someone have solution on this .

Comment: Check `putty` command to connect remote server not spring boot, then you can easily run command like localhost

Comment: I connect to the remote server using putty ,but once I logged in to the sever how to connect to the boot application which is having port 21 configured for remote commands. I tried "ssh -p 21 admin@localhost" on remote server but that was not working

Comment: Got the answer .... instead of localhost used 0.0.0.0 and also changed port 21 as this port is blocked by firewall .
for example : 
ssh -p 3000 username@0.0.0.0

Comment: But could not get the proper explanation why localhost can not be used and how to stop firewall from blocking port 21.